# How to train a new parser model for Stanford NLP from treebank?

Tags: java, parsing, nlp, stanford-nlp, linguistics

I have downloaded the [UPDT](http://stp.lingfil.uu.se/~mojgan/UPDT.html) Persian treebank ([Uppsala Persian Dependency Treebank](http://stp.lingfil.uu.se/~mojgan/UPDT.html)) and I am trying to build a dependency parser model from it using Stanford NLP. I have tried train the model using both command line and Java code, but I get exceptions in both cases.

1- Train a model using command line:

```
java -mx1500m edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser -train UPDT\train.conll 0 -saveToSerializedFile UPDT\updt.model.ser.gz
```

When I run the above command I will get this exception:

```
done [read 26 trees]. Time elapsed: 0 ms
Options parameters:
useUnknownWordSignatures 0
smoothInUnknownsThreshold 100
smartMutation false
useUnicodeType false
unknownSuffixSize 1
unknownPrefixSize 1
flexiTag false
useSignatureForKnownSmoothing false
wordClassesFile null
parserParams edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.EnglishTreebankParserParams
forceCNF false
doPCFG true
doDep true
freeDependencies false
directional true
genStop true
distance true
coarseDistance false
dcTags true
nPrune false
Train parameters:
 smooth=false
 PA=true
 GPA=false
 selSplit=false
 (0.0)
 mUnary=0
 mUnaryTags=false
 sPPT=false
 tagPA=false
 tagSelSplit=false (0.0)
 rightRec=false
 leftRec=false
 collinsPunc=false
 markov=false
 mOrd=1
 hSelSplit=false (10)
 compactGrammar=0
 postPA=false
 postGPA=false
 selPSplit=false (0.0)
 tagSelPSplit=false (0.0)
 postSplitWithBase=false
 fractionBeforeUnseenCounting=0.5
 openClassTypesThreshold=50
 preTransformer=null
 taggedFiles=null
 predictSplits=false
 splitCount=1
 splitRecombineRate=0.0
 simpleBinarizedLabels=false
 noRebinarization=false
 trainingThreads=1
 dvKBest=100
 trainingIterations=40
 batchSize=25
 regCost=1.0E-4
 qnIterationsPerBatch=1
 qnEstimates=15
 qnTolerance=15.0
 debugOutputFrequency=0
 randomSeed=0
 learningRate=0.1
 deltaMargin=0.1
 unknownNumberVector=true
 unknownDashedWordVectors=true
 unknownCapsVector=true
 unknownChineseYearVector=true
 unknownChineseNumberVector=true
 unknownChinesePercentVector=true
 dvSimplifiedModel=false
 scalingForInit=0.5
 maxTrainTimeSeconds=0
 unkWord=*UNK*
 lowercaseWordVectors=false
 transformMatrixType=DIAGONAL
 useContextWords=false
 trainWordVectors=true
 stalledIterationLimit=12
 markStrahler=false

Using EnglishTreebankParserParams splitIN=0 sPercent=false sNNP=0 sQuotes=false
sSFP=false rbGPA=false j#=false jJJ=false jNounTags=false sPPJJ=false sTRJJ=fals
e sJJCOMP=false sMoreLess=false unaryDT=false unaryRB=false unaryPRP=false reflP
RP=false unaryIN=false sCC=0 sNT=false sRB=false sAux=0 vpSubCat=false mDTV=0 sV
P=0 sVPNPAgr=false sSTag=0 mVP=false sNP%=0 sNPPRP=false dominatesV=0 dominatesI
=false dominatesC=false mCC=0 sSGapped=0 numNP=false sPoss=0 baseNP=0 sNPNNP=0 s
TMP=0 sNPADV=0 cTags=false rightPhrasal=false gpaRootVP=false splitSbar=0 mPPTOi
IN=0 cWh=0
Binarizing trees...done. Time elapsed: 12 ms
Extracting PCFG...PennTreeReader: warning: file has extra non-matching right par
enthesis [ignored]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No head rule defi
ned for _ using class edu.stanford.nlp.trees.ModCollinsHeadFinder in (_
  DELM
  DELM
  DELM
  13
  punct
  _
  _
  15
  ??????
  _
  N
  N_SING
  SING
  13
  appos
  _
  _
  16
  ???????
  _
  ADJ
  ADJ
  ADJ
  15
  amod
  _
  _
  17
  ??
  _
  P
  P
  P
  15
  prep
  _
  _
  18
  ???
  _
  N
  N_SING
  SING
  17
  pobj
  _
  _
  19
  ?
  _
  CON
  CON
  CON
  18
  cc
  _
  _
  20
  ????
  _
  N
  N_SING
  SING
  18
  conj
  _
  _
  21
  ????
  _
  N
  N_SING
  SING
  20
  poss/pc
  _
  _
  22)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.AbstractCollinsHeadFinder.determineNonTrivialH
ead(AbstractCollinsHeadFinder.java:242)
     at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.AbstractCollinsHeadFinder.determineHead(Abstra
ctCollinsHeadFinder.java:189)
     at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.AbstractCollinsHeadFinder.determineHead(Abstra
ctCollinsHeadFinder.java:140)
     at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.TreeAnnotator.transformTreeHelper(T
reeAnnotator.java:145)
     at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.TreeAnnotator.transformTree(TreeAnn
otator.java:51)
     at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.TreeAnnotatorAndBinarizer.transform
Tree(TreeAnnotatorAndBinarizer.java:104)
     at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.CompositeTreeTransformer.transformTree(Composi
teTreeTransformer.java:30)
     at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TransformingTreebank$TransformingTreebankItera
tor.next(TransformingTreebank.java:195)
     at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TransformingTreebank$TransformingTreebankItera
tor.next(TransformingTreebank.java:176)
     at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.FilteringTreebank$FilteringTreebankIterator.pr
imeNext(FilteringTreebank.java:100)
     at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.FilteringTreebank$FilteringTreebankIterator.<i
nit>(FilteringTreebank.java:85)
     at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.FilteringTreebank.iterator(FilteringTreebank.j
ava:72)
     at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.AbstractTreeExtractor.tallyTrees(Ab
stractTreeExtractor.java:64)
     at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.AbstractTreeExtractor.extract(Abstr
actTreeExtractor.java:89)
     at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.getParserFromTree
bank(LexicalizedParser.java:881)
     at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.main(LexicalizedP
arser.java:1394)
```

2- Train the model using Java code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.HasWord;
import edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser;
import edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.Options;
import edu.stanford.nlp.process.DocumentPreprocessor;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.GrammaticalStructure;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.GrammaticalStructureFactory;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.Tree;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.Treebank;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TreebankLanguagePack;


public class FromTreeBank {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String treebankPathUPDT = "src/model/UPDT.1.2/train.conll";
        String persianFilePath  = "src/txt/persianSentences.txt";

        File file = new File(treebankPathUPDT);

        Options op = new Options();   
        Treebank tr = op.tlpParams.diskTreebank();
        tr.loadPath(file);    
        LexicalizedParser lpc = LexicalizedParser.trainFromTreebank(tr,op);

        //Once the lpc is trained, use it to parse a file which contains Persian text  
        //demoDP(lpc, persianFilePath);
    }


    public static void demoDP(LexicalizedParser lp, String filename) {
        // This option shows loading, sentence-segmenting and tokenizing
        // a file using DocumentPreprocessor.
        TreebankLanguagePack tlp = lp.treebankLanguagePack(); // a PennTreebankLanguagePack for English
        GrammaticalStructureFactory gsf = null;
        if (tlp.supportsGrammaticalStructures()) {
            gsf = tlp.grammaticalStructureFactory();
        }
        // You could also create a tokenizer here (as below) and pass it
        // to DocumentPreprocessor
        for (List<HasWord> sentence : new DocumentPreprocessor(filename)) {
            Tree parse = lp.apply(sentence);
            parse.pennPrint();
            System.out.println();
            if (gsf != null) {
                GrammaticalStructure gs = gsf.newGrammaticalStructure(parse);
                Collection tdl = gs.typedDependenciesCCprocessed();
                System.out.println(tdl);
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The Above Java program also make this exception:

```
Options parameters:
useUnknownWordSignatures 0
smoothInUnknownsThreshold 100
smartMutation false
useUnicodeType false
unknownSuffixSize 1
unknownPrefixSize 1
flexiTag false
useSignatureForKnownSmoothing false
wordClassesFile null
parserParams edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.EnglishTreebankParserParams
forceCNF false
doPCFG true
doDep true
freeDependencies false
directional true
genStop true
distance true
coarseDistance false
dcTags true
nPrune false
Train parameters:
 smooth=false
 PA=true
 GPA=false
 selSplit=false
 (0.0)
 mUnary=0
 mUnaryTags=false
 sPPT=false
 tagPA=false
 tagSelSplit=false (0.0)
 rightRec=false
 leftRec=false
 collinsPunc=false
 markov=false
 mOrd=1
 hSelSplit=false (10)
 compactGrammar=0
 postPA=false
 postGPA=false
 selPSplit=false (0.0)
 tagSelPSplit=false (0.0)
 postSplitWithBase=false
 fractionBeforeUnseenCounting=0.5
 openClassTypesThreshold=50
 preTransformer=null
 taggedFiles=null
 predictSplits=false
 splitCount=1
 splitRecombineRate=0.0
 simpleBinarizedLabels=false
 noRebinarization=false
 trainingThreads=1
 dvKBest=100
 trainingIterations=40
 batchSize=25
 regCost=1.0E-4
 qnIterationsPerBatch=1
 qnEstimates=15
 qnTolerance=15.0
 debugOutputFrequency=0
 randomSeed=0
 learningRate=0.1
 deltaMargin=0.1
 unknownNumberVector=true
 unknownDashedWordVectors=true
 unknownCapsVector=true
 unknownChineseYearVector=true
 unknownChineseNumberVector=true
 unknownChinesePercentVector=true
 dvSimplifiedModel=false
 scalingForInit=0.5
 maxTrainTimeSeconds=0
 unkWord=*UNK*
 lowercaseWordVectors=false
 transformMatrixType=DIAGONAL
 useContextWords=false
 trainWordVectors=true
 stalledIterationLimit=12
 markStrahler=false

Using EnglishTreebankParserParams splitIN=0 sPercent=false sNNP=0 sQuotes=false sSFP=false rbGPA=false j#=false jJJ=false jNounTags=false sPPJJ=false sTRJJ=false sJJCOMP=false sMoreLess=false unaryDT=false unaryRB=false unaryPRP=false reflPRP=false unaryIN=false sCC=0 sNT=false sRB=false sAux=0 vpSubCat=false mDTV=0 sVP=0 sVPNPAgr=false sSTag=0 mVP=false sNP%=0 sNPPRP=false dominatesV=0 dominatesI=false dominatesC=false mCC=0 sSGapped=0 numNP=false sPoss=0 baseNP=0 sNPNNP=0 sTMP=0 sNPADV=0 cTags=false rightPhrasal=false gpaRootVP=false splitSbar=0 mPPTOiIN=0 cWh=0
Binarizing trees...done. Time elapsed: 122 ms
Extracting PCFG...PennTreeReader: warning: file has extra non-matching right parenthesis [ignored]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No head rule defined for _ using class edu.stanford.nlp.trees.ModCollinsHeadFinder in (_
  DELM
  DELM
  DELM
  13
  punct
  _
  _
  15
  تلفیقی
  _
  N
  N_SING
  SING
  13
  appos
  _
  _
  16
  طنزآمیز
  _
  ADJ
  ADJ
  ADJ
  15
  amod
  _
  _
  17
  از
  _
  P
  P
  P
  15
  prep
  _
  _
  18
  اسم
  _
  N
  N_SING
  SING
  17
  pobj
  _
  _
  19
  و
  _
  CON
  CON
  CON
  18
  cc
  _
  _
  20
  شیوه
  _
  N
  N_SING
  SING
  18
  conj
  _
  _
  21
  کارش
  _
  N
  N_SING
  SING
  20
  poss/pc
  _
  _
  22)


    at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.AbstractCollinsHeadFinder.determineNonTrivialHead(AbstractCollinsHeadFinder.java:242)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.AbstractCollinsHeadFinder.determineHead(AbstractCollinsHeadFinder.java:189)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.AbstractCollinsHeadFinder.determineHead(AbstractCollinsHeadFinder.java:140)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.TreeAnnotator.transformTreeHelper(TreeAnnotator.java:145)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.TreeAnnotator.transformTree(TreeAnnotator.java:51)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.TreeAnnotatorAndBinarizer.transformTree(TreeAnnotatorAndBinarizer.java:104)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.CompositeTreeTransformer.transformTree(CompositeTreeTransformer.java:30)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TransformingTreebank$TransformingTreebankIterator.next(TransformingTreebank.java:195)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TransformingTreebank$TransformingTreebankIterator.next(TransformingTreebank.java:176)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.FilteringTreebank$FilteringTreebankIterator.primeNext(FilteringTreebank.java:100)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.FilteringTreebank$FilteringTreebankIterator.<init>(FilteringTreebank.java:85)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.FilteringTreebank.iterator(FilteringTreebank.java:72)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.AbstractTreeExtractor.tallyTrees(AbstractTreeExtractor.java:64)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.AbstractTreeExtractor.extract(AbstractTreeExtractor.java:89)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.getParserFromTreebank(LexicalizedParser.java:881)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.trainFromTreebank(LexicalizedParser.java:267)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.trainFromTreebank(LexicalizedParser.java:278)
    at FromTreeBank.main(FromTreeBank.java:46)
```

Actually, I am not sure if the command-line or Java code is correct or not. I can't figure out what is missing in the command-line or the Java code, I would be the most grateful if someone tell me why I get these exceptions and what is wrong? Or suggest any better way to train a model from a treebank.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

if you still wondering why you get this error, it is same as said in error. For this character "_" (its name is underscore I think) there is no rule defined in edu.stanford.nlp.trees.ModCollinsHeadFinder class.

I have same thing for parenthesis character and after deleting data which contain parenthesis now I can train stanford parser without error. I did not tried yet for finding direct solution which solve it by changing code.Easiest way is for you to delete data which contain that character like me.

If you solved your problem already can you share it? I also need some more knowledge about stanford parser.

Comment: The problem is the last bit where you ask for if they solved the problem, it looks like an answer that is just asking for the solution, which would have been better fared as a comment. However, the first part of your text is an OK answer. But people doing reviews may miss that and just read the last line, such is the way. The reason it's been seen recently, is that it came up in a review queue. I've taken the time now to update the language usage and improved the English.

Comment: @DesertTigerTR Don't take it too seriously, Draken is right, the first part of the answer could be quite ok, but the very last sentence is better suited as a comment. We are all here to learn, to improve, and at last, to share some knowledge if we can.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest issue here is that you are trying to train a constituency tree parser (aka phrase-structure tree parser) with a dependency treebank, which is not going to work.

CoreNLP also comes with a neural-network based dependency parser, which you could train with the UPDT data. Take a look at the [project page](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/nndep.shtml) of the parser for instructions on how to train a model.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply replace all "(" with "-LRB-" and all ")" with "-RRB-" in your "trainFile.conll" (or any other format) and rerun the parser.
That worked for me.